Strange symbols (ansi) in a log file when using tracing_subscriber
I have weird symbols added to a log file, I guess its some prettification with ANSI for terminal output:
2024-10-23T00:00:19.268093Z TRACE process_token{^[[3mmint^[[0m^[[2m=^[[0m"FxcVT3p9Mfrw84DPYrNc4o2MHryuL8Wvcmgqrjtbpump"}

But I expected it should be this
2024-10-23T00:00:19.268093Z TRACE process_token{mint="FxcVT3p9Mfrw84DPYrNc4o2MHryuL8Wvcmgqrjtbpump"}

Thats my log writing setup
use tracing::{Level, info, error, trace, warn, debug, instrument};
use tracing_subscriber::{Layer, Registry, prelude::*, filter};
use tracing_appender::rolling::daily;
use tracing_appender::non_blocking::WorkerGuard;
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::FmtSpan;

fn main() {
    let file_appender = daily("logs", "app.log");
    let (non_blocking_appender, guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(file_appender);

    let error_file_appender = daily("logs", "error.log");
    let (non_blocking_error_appender, error_guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(error_file_appender);
    
    let debug_file_layer = tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer()
        .with_writer(non_blocking_appender)
        .with_ansi(false)
        .with_target(false)
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .with_filter(filter::LevelFilter::TRACE);

    let console_layer = tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer()
        .with_ansi(true)
        .with_target(false)
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .with_filter(filter::LevelFilter::INFO);

    let subscriber = Registry::default()
        .with(console_layer)
        .with(debug_file_layer);
        //.with(error_file_layer);

    // Set the subscriber as the default
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber)
        .expect("Failed to set subscriber");


    process_token("test data");
}

#[instrument]
fn process_token(mint: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    Ok(())
}


I have another file writer + terminal printer as well.
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "tracing-bug"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
tracing = "0.1.40"
tracing-appender = "0.2.3"
tracing-subscriber = "0.3.18"

How I can remove those characters?

Try putting .with (debug_file_layer) before .with (console_layer)

This code prints both to terminal and to file.
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "first-project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
tracing-subscriber = "0.3.18"
tracing-appender = "0.2.3"
futures = "0.3.31"
tracing = "0.1.40"

Rust Code
use futures::executor;
use tracing::instrument;
use tracing_appender::rolling::daily;
use tracing_subscriber::{fmt, layer::SubscriberExt, util::SubscriberInitExt, Layer};

#[instrument()]
async fn process_token(mint: &str) {}

fn main() {
    // File appender (no ANSI formatting)
    let file_appender = daily("logs", "app.log");
    let (non_blocking_file, _guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(file_appender);
    let file_layer = fmt::layer()
        .with_writer(non_blocking_file)
        .with_ansi(false) // Disable ANSI for file
        .with_target(false)
        .with_span_events(fmt::format::FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .with_filter(tracing_subscriber::filter::LevelFilter::TRACE); // Apply TRACE level filter

    // Terminal appender (with ANSI formatting)
    let terminal_layer = fmt::layer()
        .with_ansi(true) // Enable ANSI for terminal output
        .with_target(false)
        .with_span_events(fmt::format::FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .with_filter(tracing_subscriber::filter::LevelFilter::TRACE); // Apply TRACE level filter

    // Combine both layers
    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(file_layer) // File layer without ANSI
        .with(terminal_layer) // Terminal layer with ANSI
        .init();

    executor::block_on(process_token("SomeToken"));
}

This code prints to terminal:
2024-10-23T16:39:07.689402Z  INFO process_token{mint="SomeToken"}: close time.busy=13.3µs time.idle=188µs

This code also prints to file:
2024-10-23T16:39:07.689278Z  INFO process_token{mint="SomeToken"}: close time.busy=13.3µs time.idle=50.9µs


What the... we even have the same package versions... Inspecting... I found something: if I remove my terminal printer it works properly

I've updated my example with the full source so the problem is easy to repeat

@Eugene , in your code, debug_file_layer is of type Layer. but console_layer is of strange type, make it also of type tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer(). Then register layers as tracing_subscriber::registry().with(debug_file_layer).with(console_layer).init(); and it will work. (as I do in the code)

Do you mean ::<tracing_subscriber::Registry>? I removed it and its still the same

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This is a working solution based on your code :)
use tracing::{Level, info, error, trace, warn, debug, instrument};
use tracing_subscriber::{Layer, Registry, prelude::*, filter};
use tracing_appender::rolling::daily;
use tracing_appender::non_blocking::WorkerGuard;
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::FmtSpan;

fn main() {
    let file_appender = daily("logs", "app.log");
    let (non_blocking_appender, guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(file_appender);

    let error_file_appender = daily("logs", "error.log");
    let (non_blocking_error_appender, error_guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(error_file_appender);
    
    let debug_file_layer = tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer()
        .with_writer(non_blocking_appender)
        .with_ansi(false)
        .with_target(false)
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .with_filter(filter::LevelFilter::TRACE);

    let console_layer = tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer()
        .with_ansi(true)
        .with_target(false)
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .with_filter(filter::LevelFilter::INFO);

    //let subscriber = Registry::default()
    //    .with(console_layer)
    //    .with(debug_file_layer).init();
    //    //.with(error_file_layer);
    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(debug_file_layer) // File layer without ANSI
        .with(console_layer) // Terminal layer with ANSI
        .init();

    // Set the subscriber as the default
    //tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber)
    //    .expect("Failed to set subscriber");       

    process_token("test data");
}

#[instrument]
fn process_token(mint: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    Ok(())
}


Thank you man! The sorting was the problem, if console layer with ANSI on is the last it works correctly.
I suggest you remove the code in your answer and write just what you changed exactly. set_global_default you cant remove, my logging will break. And I will mark it as an answer.
